# Which tool allows bending a mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh, geometry

In the [feature video](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.72/Feature_Videos) of version 2.72 the mesh intersection tool is introduced. Which tool is used to bend the scaled and loop-cut cube here?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the Bend Tool, `Mesh -> Transform -> Bend`

Shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd>.

It is documented as operator in the [API](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_72_release/bpy.ops.transform.html?highlight=bpy.ops.transform.bend#bpy.ops.transform.bend)

> Bend selected items between the 3D cursor and the mouse

[image]

The Warp function that used to be on Shift W is from 2.70 replaced by the Bend tool. The Warp Tool is still there, but you have to search for it. In the feature video you can actually hear the commenter telling he is using the Bend Tool.

Comment: Is it mentioned in docs? I couldn't find a reference?

Comment: The Bend Tool was introduced in Blender 2.70. To my knowledge it is an undocumented feature, or at least a very well hidden one.

Comment: The Warp function that used to be on Shift W is from 2.70 replaced by the Bend tool (Mac). The Warp Tool is still there, but you have to search for it.

Comment: Thanks, I hope my edits are ok for you (restored the comment from a deleted answer).

Comment: @user1374 You _dont_ have to search for the warp too, its in `Mesh -> Transform -> Warp`

Answer (score -2):

I know this is an old question, but for those who still need help, you can go into edit mode>Mesh>Symmetrize.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: this question is asking about the bend tool, not symmetry.