# How does the bend tool work?

Tags: modeling, mesh

How does the bend tool (<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>W</kbd>) work? I couldn't find any mention of it in the wiki or in the [new documentation](http://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/deforming.html).

When I tried to use it, I failed:

[image]

It seems to use 3D cursor position, as well as the angle and distance from the mouse cursor.

What do the *Radius* and *Bend Angle* do? How do they affect the result?

What is an example use-case of this tool in action?

Comment: I remember Campbell himself made a feature video about this on youtube. fyi

Comment: @LeonCheung Wow, thanks. That explained everything :D

Comment: [Here's the link](http://youtu.be/jnSK7162mNw) in case anyone else is reading this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *Bend Tool* rotates around the 3D cursor and bends the selected parts of a mesh toward the mouse cursor position.

The tool is explained in [this video](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.72/Feature_Videos).

Start position (white cross indicates position of mouse cursor)

[image]

End position and effect:

[image]

For predictable results use the bend tool in the orthographic modes.

Start position with 3D cursor at center:

[image]

Similar result:

[image]

Related:

- [Which tool allows bending a mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17905/which-tool-allows-bending-a-mesh)

Comment: Is there way to accurately set mouse curor location for the usage of Bend tool?

Comment: Yes. Press Shift + S for setting 3D Cursor Position.

Comment: @LeonCheung unfortunately no, that is why I prefer the spin tool.

Comment: @LeonCheung [Precisely move the 3D cursor](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/13828/2217)

Comment: @David I think Leon Cheung wants to precisely set the *mouse* cursor location, e.g. via keyboard inputs.