# Easiest Way to BEND a plank into a U shape?

Tags: bezier-curves

There's so many tutorials online I'm royally confused. Most are way more complicated than I think I need here .. but I am looking for the easiest way to bend or curve a 50 x 20 x 2 inch "plank" into a U shape. Then I want to add subdivisions and smooth to slightly round all the edges. Any suggestions?

Comment: Thus far I added a simple deform but it's bending on the wrong axis. I'll check it out - thank you sir!

Comment: Yes, can be a little tricky to use. Apply all transfrormations and remember that by default the bending axis is X. I think that also using the Warp tool is a good way to follow, give it a try.

Comment: I'm thinking about something like this: http://gph.is/1HAgT6h

Comment: According to the directions on your link for adding Lattice -- There's no "Lattice Object" icon in v2.75. As seen here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ppb1.png consequently when I just try adding a Lattice modifer nothing happens.

Comment: Ok. I'll try the warp tool. Which I think is a deformer(?) So I add that Warp and then... nothing. I figit with the controls and nothing. When I click apply I get an error "Modifer is disabled, skipping apply"

Comment: No, by saying the "warp tool" I would not intend the modifier, but a command you can run in edit mode (http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/3D_interaction/Transformations/Advanced/Warp). From 2.70 I think is called "Bend"(http://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/deforming/bend.html?highlight=bend )...anyway is what you get by pressing shift+w. See related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17905/which-tool-allows-bending-a-mesh