# Model a Curved Edge

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, edit-mode

[image: an exmaple lamppost]

I'm trying to make a lamppost with a curved metal (like in the picture) and I don't know how to make the curved bit on top.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21763/how-does-the-bend-tool-work and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17905/which-tool-allows-bending-a-mesh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively (to my [other answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/38630/5705)), you could model the whole lamp shape from a curve.  Just hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Curve* > *Bezier*.  Then give the curve some thickness by setting the *bevel* to something other than `0` and setting the *fill* to *full* under the *data* properties panel.

[image]

In edit mode you can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Click to add new control points and use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to adjust the relative bevel thickness of the control points to create a shape like this.

[image]

Once you have the basic curvature down you can convert the curve to a mesh with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> > *Mesh From Curve* and model the finer details.

Answer (score 4):

I would use the *spin* tool.  Spin extrudes a portion of geometry along a radial curve (portion of a circle).  Just place the 3D cursor at the center of the curve, be sure you are in side view (<kbd>NumPad 3</kbd>) or else the direction of extrusion will be strange, select the top ring of the straight part, and hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.  Then hit <kbd>F6</kbd> and you can tweak the settings to get the curve you want.

[image]

You can adjust the curve angle with the *angle* spinner and the resolution of the extrusion with the *steps* spinner.  You can also adjust the center of the curve (by default this is set to the location of the 3D cursor), and the axis (as a vector) around which to rotate the extrusion (by default this is perpendicular to the view plane).